# How to have more precision in multitouch event?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, multi-touch

I have to test multitouch event on iPhone screen (from iPhone 4s to latest device).

The points, up to 5 as iPhone can't detect more points as I read, are well separately detected when they have at least 5mm space between each others. 
But if I have more touch points with a radius about 5mm and only about 2 mm between each points, they are detected as a single point.
How can I improve accuracy and detect multiple close points ?

[image]

Comment: Hi there - could you perhaps post some code on how you are detecting this event? Are you using location(in: ) or trying to use preciseLocation(in: ) for the touches?

Comment: I followed Apple examples and implemented touch begin and touch ended in my uiview. But the problem is that I only retrieve one uitouch object in the touches array in touch start func.